# Android Video Streaming

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, media-player

I am using MediaPlayer to play an online video. The link for the video I use is "**https://**" link. But it shows the following error:

**Command PLAYER_SET_DATA_SOURCE completed with an error or info PVMFErrNotSupported**

And when I change this link to "**http://**" the video playback starts perfectly.
What can be the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can u please put your code here

Comment: MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); 
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);  
mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();   
mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this); 
mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);  
mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);  
mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this); 
mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HTTPS is not supported before Android 3.1.** Please have a look on the following link

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

[image]